# comparing the name of different files

Tags: python-3.x

I have listed the name of particular files in a directory, also, I have a list of other files that are within another directory. Now, I want to retrieve the name of the files that are common in these 2 directories. Here is my code:

```
import os
result = listdir("C:\\Users\\Dbs_finalFINAL", "*Not_Null.txt")
repo_dataset=open("C:\\Users\\repositories_No_zero_datasets.txt")
for i in  result:        
    x=i[:-13] # only extracting the names without "Not_Null.txt" extension
    if str(x)==(str(l) for l in repo_dataset):
        print (x)
    else:
        print("not meet")
```

Desired outcome:
I want to see a list of common files

What I see is:
"not meet"

Any help, please?

Comment: You are getting 'not meet', it means Dbs_finalFINAL dir does not have any file.

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL, it does have files. And there are matching files, but, some how the code is wrong! I guess

Comment: is your code is working because you wrote listdir instead of os.listdir? Also have you tried to print result

Comment: os.listdir takes only one argument, why you have passes second too?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I needed to use strip() function on each side to make them have equal length.